# Which LaTeX editor have autocompletion with a hotkey (like in commanline `tab`)

Tags: texstudio, editors, auto-completion

I use TeXstudio, it is pretty good and it autocompletion is great, but I was wondering if there is any editor I has autocompletion hotkey (like `Tab` in commandline)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: TeXstudio has `tab` autocompletion if the autocompleter window is open.

Comment: @Troy I know, but I need something when I click tap I get all possible options

Comment: TeXworks has something similar to the command-line. Press tab as often as needed to get to the one you want.

Comment: You could use one of the "hackables": [atom](http://atom.io/), [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/). All of these should be able to support tab autocomplete the way you describe!

Comment: Nope, I reviewed atomic and emacs, none is what I asked for.